# In Hide, why was there a cold spot?

Tags: doctor-who

In the episode "Hide" from the seventh series of Doctor Who, they are tracking the lady of the well.

However

> It turns out that the well is really a wormhole.

However in the music room they found a cold spot, and the Doctor marks it with chalk. This spot seems unrelated to any of the rest of the events/explanation.

So why was there a cold spot, why was it a perfect circle, and why did the chalk behave the way it did?

Comment: "Cold spots" are usually indicative of paranormal/ghostly activity. It does seem odd that this phenomenon would be present in a time traveling accident.

Comment: The door closest to the circle is the door that acts as a gateway between the pocket dimension and the Doctor's dimension. Why it was cold is that energy from this plane may have been leaking into it (making the area colder). As for why it behaved that way--- dramatic license.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen that episode, but a possible interpretation ocurs to me.

You've probably heard of the [dark energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy), which we think is making the expansion of the universe accelerate. From a physicist's perspective dark energy can be modelled as a vacuum energy, and if there are multiple bubble universes then they may have different vacuum energies. There has been speculation that bubble universes may collide, and if they do so the difference in vacuum energy will make the collision point look cold in one universe and hot in the other. The calculation is described [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.5128), but be warned that the paper is utterly impenetrable for non-nerds.

So if the well is a tunnel between universes it's quite possible that it would have a different temperature.

But, but, but, but ...

Firstly this is all highly speculative since there are no widely accepted theories to describe this sort of thing. The paper I linked should be regarded as an amusing pastime for theoretical physicists rather than hard science.

Secondly the collision is assumed to occur while both universes are undergoing [inflation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_inflation), and their vacuum energies (due to the inflaton field) were many orders of magnitude greater than dark energy. For a collision between two universes like ours the vacuum energy difference, and hence the temperature difference of the contact patch, would be immeasurably low.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good clue is that the chalk circle is around about the size of the cross-section of the Tardis.

This suggests it was an artefact / side effect of the traveller's malfunctional prototype spacetime machine. It was the identifying of this machine malfunction (reminiscent of the Tardis's problems throughout *The Lodger*) that gave the Doctor his big nudge that the problem was dimensional traversal not ghosts.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it was to  strengthen the thought in the viewers mind that this was a haunting, rather than any other phenomenon. [Cold Spots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_spot) have often been reported at haunted locations, and are associated with paranormal activity. The inclusion of one in this episode plays to the spooky feeling of the house, even though the 'ghost' was not actually a ghost.

Comment: Could my down-voter please comment as to the problem with my suggestion?

Comment: This type of answer might not be the in-universe answer that one looks for when asking an in-universe question, but sometimes the writers don't think things through enough and answers like this can be plausible, even if it is not what we want. I'm not the one who gave the -1, but the person who gave it probably didn't want a meta-universe answer.

Comment: @Sheph, Ah, I see. The question is not why the story authors thought to include a cold spot, more why the story elements lead to a cold spot. I'm not really familiar with the terms in-universe and meta-universe.